# Need to convert to decimal but don't know the base of JPZYPZ

Tags: math, numbers, decimal, radix

I need to convert this code to a decimal number but I can't tell what base was used to generate it as all letters:

```
JPZYPZ
```

How can I figure out what type of "number" this is?

Answer (score 4):

Just a guess, but based on the "largest" letter Z, I'd go with base-36.

You can play around with different bases in here: http://www.translatorscafe.com/cafe/units-converter/numbers/calculator/decimal-to-base-36 .

Answer (score 3):

The simple answer is that you cannot figure out what that is from this information. You need to ask whoever generated it to tell you the code.

If you have a lot of such numbers and you know that they are all encoded the same way, then you might feel more confident to take an educated guess.